# RegExp for replacing line breaks with br, on lines that doesnt contain only a tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Is there a RegExp i could use in String.replace() to replace line breaks with br tags, in text containing html tags...as if it didnt contain tags( completely ignore lines which contain only tags).

e.g if i have a following text+html input.

```
<p>
    line one
    line <b>two</b>bold
    line three
</p>
```

would become

```
<p>
    line one<br>
    line <b>two</b>bold<br>
    line three
</p>
```

Any help is much aprechiated

Comment: What's the difference between line one and line three?

Comment: But, your `line one` *has* a line containing only a tag before it, right (`<p>`)? According to your rules it should not have a `<br>` in such a case. Shouldn't it just be "all lines except the last one need a `<br>`"?

Comment: You are right, i updated the post to make it more clear what i need.
Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so clear, but this would be an idea:

```
str = str.replace(/([^>]) *\r?\n(?! *<)/g, "$1<br>");
```

Replaces `\r?\n` to `<br>` if preceded by a non `>` and any amount of spaces. Checking with a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), if there's no `<` preceded by any amount of spaces after it.

Where I assumed you want to avoid something like `<br><br>` or `<br></p>` :)

Test: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne5tt2x3/), [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jF4tH8/2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good job for regex. You're probably better off using a `FIFO` buffer to read 2 lines at a time, and if the first one has only a tag (which you can use a regex to detect I guess), you just read the next line (discarding the line with the tag) and redo. If you don't detect a tag in the first line, append `<br>` to the second line and replace the line.

Here's a quick-n-dirty regex to parse tags (_note that this is just for demonstration, it will *not* handle malformed tags and probably will break easily_):

`<[a-z]+>`

and [here's](http://regex101.com/r/pB2pG5/1) somewhere to play with it.

For the buffer you can use an `Array` with `shift()` and `push()` to get rid of the old line and read in the next line respectively. Check the first element in the array with the regex, if it passes, change the second element and replace the string in the file with your new one.

Here's what it should look like:

```
< test = ['first', 'second']
> Array [ "first", "second" ]
< test.shift()
> "first"
< test.push('third')
> 2
< test
> Array [ "second", "third" ]
```

*`<` is my input to the javascript console and `>` is what it returns.*